# registration form to two PDF files then send them to an emails

Tags: php, windows, email, pdf, hosting

We have a website registration form, where the fields will need to be inserted into 2 PDF documents and then send those PDF documents via email to our customer service department, after reading blogs and watch videos, I can not find the best solution for our problem, how can we accomplish that using html, php in a windows hosting account?

Comment: If we have the PDF documents, but we do not know how to auto-populate some fields from those PDF documents and then send them to our emails

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about real PDF forms you may check out the [SetaPDF-FormFiller](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) component (not free!). It allows you to fill in a PDF forms (AcroForm/XFA) in PHP. If it is a plain flat PDF document, you can use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to import the pages into [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and write the dynamic content to the specific locations.

To send the resulting PDF I would suggest a common email class like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to store those pdf files with an unique id name, and just send the links to them in the mail.
So you can do it with just the mail() function after build the pdf files. 
You can use a library as FPDF (www.fpdf.org) to create the files.

If you must put the pdf files inside the mail, you can do it with the phpmailer library.